# Storing files Django

Tags: python, django, file, django-models, local-storage

I am building an website using django in which I have to store a lot of files.

I have a view, which takes file from the user and saves it.

```
def store(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        sender = request.POST['sender']
        file = request.POST['file']
```

I have a model in which i save these data:

```
class t_data(models.Model):
    sender = models.TextField()
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files')
```

and I have this on my settings file:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"media")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Many files can have same name. Should I rename before saving them? How should I save them. There will be many users, So how can I distinguish files for each user?

my question is : **What is the best way to store files in a django application?**Please

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. It creates a random string and adds it to the file name - [How to Rename an Image or File in an Upload in Django](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-rename-an-image-or-file-in-an-upload-Django.php)